# TSHARK DNS to LOGFILE

Tags: bash, tee, tshark

I'm trying to get this command to output to a logfile.. when I use the tee command - it goes straight to the tshark help screen, without the tee command, it prints the DNS lines to the screen properly. How can i proper log the screen for this?

> sudo tshark -i enp2s0 -f "src port 53" -n -T fields -e ip.dst -e dns.qry.name -e dns.a -w | tee -a logfile.log

Comment: What does the tshark documentation say about logfiles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are teeing to a logfile and using -T fields, so the expected output is text.
The problem is that you are using `-w`, which changes the output to packet bits. Per [tshark's manpage](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html):

```
-w <outfile> | -
  Write raw packet data to outfile or to the standard output if outfile is '-'.

  NOTE: -w provides raw packet data, not text. If you want text output you need 
  to redirect stdout (e.g. using '>'), don't use the -w option for this.
```

The secondary problem is that you are specifying `-w` without also specifying an output file or stdin. There won't be any syntax errors with tshark if you remove the `-w` flag.

Comment: Thank you! I overlooked the "-w"
It works fine now!